# How to change all label forecolor with a click of a button

Tags: c#, winforms, button, label

I want to create a button that will change the forecolor of a label with a button click. But whenever I click the button it only changes the forecolor of a label that is not in the panel.
Here's my code :

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.BackColor = Color.White;
    foreach(Control l in Controls)
    {
        if(l is Label)
        {
            l.ForeColor = Color.Black;
        }           
    }
}
```

I've tried using

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.BackColor = Color.White;
    foreach(Label l in Controls)
    {                
        l.ForeColor = Color.Black;
    }
}
```

but it gives me an error saying it is unable to cast object of type `System.Windows.Forms.Panel` to type `System.Windows.Forms.Label`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot do this

```
foreach(Label l in Controls)
```

because not all `Control` in `Controls` is of `Label` type

Do it with LINQ

```
foreach(Label l in panel.Controls.OfType<Label>())
    l.ForeColor = Color.Black
```

This way, you will selectively only get `Control` of type `Label` from `Controls` in the first place

Edit:

If you have multiple panels in one form and you want to change all the color of the labels inside all panels, you could do multiple loop

```
foreach(Panel p in Controls.OfType<Panel>())
    foreach(Label l in p.Controls.OfType<Label>())    
        l.ForeColor = Color.Black;
```

And just in case you have some `Label`s which are not in the panel but in the form, you can combine the above with

```
foreach(Label l in Controls.OfType<Label>())    
    l.ForeColor = Color.Black;
```

Comment: but this code only help me change the forecolor of label that's not in the panel

Comment: @Kenneth You could change the label in the panel by taking controls of the panel. See my updated answer

Comment: @Kenneth I updated my answer, please replace `panel` in my code with your `panel` object's name

Comment: So with this code i need to specify every panel that i have

Comment: @Kenneth Are all you panels in the form?

Comment: @Kenneth Then you can loop over all the panels in the form first before you change the label fore color on each panel. See my edited answer

Comment: @Kenneth Did you get what you need by the double iteration above?

Comment: yes essentially you are doing a double loop that first gets all the panels in the form then looping all the panels that have labels to change its color

Comment: @Kenneth great! Yes, you could do this or you could also make recursive search. But the key is the `OfType<Panel>` and `OfType<Label>`. Once you know this, the rests are pretty much adjustable. ;)

Answer (score 3):

You can filter the controls with Linq:

```
foreach (Label l in Controls.OfType<Label>())
{
    l.ForeColor = Color.Black;
}
```

Edit:

If you have a deeper hierarchy of controls, you can do it recursive:

```
private void SetLabelBlack(Control ctrl)
{
    foreach (Control c in ctrl.Controls)
    {
        Label l = c as Label;
        if (l != null)
        {
            l.ForeColor = Color.Black;
        }
        else
        {
            SetLabelBlack(c);
        }
    }
}
```

And call it like this:

```
SetLabelBlack(this);
```

Answer (score 1):

As the error suggests you have to check its type!

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
this.BackColor = Color.White;
foreach(Control l in Controls)
{
    if(l.GetType()==typeof(System.Windows.Forms.Label))
    {
        l.ForeColor = Color.Black;
    }           
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add all labels that you want to update in a list(List). Then iterate over all labels in that list and update the foreground color. panel.Controls returns only the controls that are in that panel, so if the label that you want to update is not in that panel  panel.Controls will not work, moreover it iterates only over immediate children of that panel. In the panel you can have another panel that contains a panel and etc...

Answer (score -1):

```
foreach(Control c in this.Controls)
                {
                    if(c is Label)
                    {
                        Label b = c as Label;
                        b.ForeColor = Color.White;
                    }
                }
```

Comment: Although this code might (or might not) solve the problem, a good answer should always explain what the code does and how it helps.